# Python combining two variable statements into one for numpy functions

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
import numpy as np, random

def simulation(low, high, num_pairs):
    c = np.round(np.random.uniform(low, high, num_pairs), 2)
    n = np.round((0.4*c-0.8), 2) # calculate rounded value
    n = np.where(n < 0, 0, n) # if negative `n`, make zero, else `n`
    return list(zip(c, n))
```

Calling this:

```
c_n_pairs = simulation(0, 15, 10)
print(*c_n_pairs, sep = "\n")
```

Outputs:

```
(5.69, 1.48)
(11.33, 3.73)
(7.16, 2.06)
(2.93, 0.37)
(8.47, 2.59)
(12.82, 4.33)
(12.84, 4.34)
(7.12, 2.05)
(7.11, 2.04)
(0.07, 0.0)
```

What I have works, but I'm wondering about the two `n` statements and if those can  be consolidated into one.

```
    n = np.round((0.4*c-0.8), 2) # calculate rounded value
    n = np.where(n < 0, 0, n) # if negative `n`, make zero, else `n`
```

Comment: Right, I was caught between a couple different thoughts and didn't think that through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.maximum` to take the elementwise maximum for an array.
This allows you to check if each element is less than zero and replace it with zero if this is the case, exactly the same as `np.where`.

```
def simulation(low, high, num_pairs):
    c = np.round(np.random.uniform(low, high, num_pairs), 2)
    n = np.maximum(np.round((0.4*c-0.8), 2), 0)
    return list(zip(c, n))
```

Comment: `np.zeros(c.size)` is redunded `0` is enogh